# android emulator is not showing display . .

Tags: android

In AVD manager if i click start the AVD, launching status is showing and the emulator process in task manager is created. but the AVD is not displaying. I am having the same problem with eclipse also. the eclipse console displaying that :

[2012-04-29 10:33:53 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'DeployAVD'

and nothing happens after that. what is the problem here??

thanks.

Comment: Do you get an emulator window border, with a black simulated screen inside?  (If so, give it 10-15 minutes, really).  Or do you not get any window created at all?

Comment: delete old avd and create new one....

Comment: I have some experience in running simple applications using ADT platform. But in the present situation, there is no window at all. I have already deleted and created AVDs and tried with new ones.

Comment: what version are all of your packages (adt, sdk-tools, sdk, avd, etc)?

Comment: all the tools are latest versions. i have just downloaded them few hours back.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have enough memory..

did u create a virtual device in AVD manager?try creating a new one...

and usually avd takes quite some time to load....

Comment: I have 4GB of ram. i am nearly waiting from 20 minutes. is there anything like path settings?? I am using Java7 and all android and eclipse tools are downloaded just few hours back.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Da1jlmwuW_w

watch these 2...everything is there......
and 4Gb is quite enough...

Comment: Thats what i have done exactly. except that, in the current version of SDK, there are separate AVD manager, SDK manager. after installing all, if i create a new AVD and start it, the starting progrees is displayed after that nothing is happend even after 1 hour. Of course, starting AVD may takes a lot of time. but it doesnt seems like that. the cpu is free. no system busy is found. Even if i want to shutdown the system, the created emulator processes are blocking system shutdown. is there anything to post something like logs etc.?

Comment: is there anything like path settings??

yes,you have to tell eclipse where android sdk is located..
window->preferences->android
and browse the sdk location...C:\android-sdk-windows

Comment: As a last step, i have copied the entire sdk folder and eclipse folder to one of my another laptop. everything is fine on that laptop.